# How do i request an Array from the controller from inside a javascript code

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, openlayers

I am using Spring boot, JPA with mysql, and thymeleaf and openlayers for the map.

So i have a map, and on this map there are dynamically generated markers for different places. What I want is when I click any of those markers to send the name of the marker to my controller and in response get an array of fishes that can be caught in this specific area and then display the names and pictures of the fishes in a dynamically generated list located on the sidebar . I cant think on how I can achieve that. Ive made a HTML page to show how I want it to look.
[image]

I was thinking about making a get request and giving the name as a path variable but then idk how I can do that request from the javascript when the button is clicked. Any ideas or concepts that I can read about are apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most DOM elements in html are accessible in javascript via something like document.getelementbyid and typically if I remember this correctly most of the objects you can do something like domobject.addEventListener("click", myScript); and in myScripy make an http call to spring requesting the list of fish. I recommend setting some breakpoints in your JavaScript code via the dev console in your browser and looking through some of the objects that are produced

You can make a get request like described here.  developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: i may have described it poorly i already have the onclick event made I just don't know how to make the Get request from inside the javascript

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the markers would be similar to this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html, but instead of showing a popup you make a GET request for more data

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
  const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature) {
    return feature;
  });
  if (feature) {
    const name = feature.get('name');
    // now make get request
    // ....
  }
});
```

If you are requesting an image you could use xhr as in [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Tile.html#~LoadFunction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Tile.html#%7ELoadFunction) or you could use fetch, similar to:

```
fetch(url).then(function(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.blob();
  }
}).then(function(result) {
  if (result) {
    const imagesrc = URL.createObjectURL(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: yes i have the onclick event just like this one my question may be stupid but how do I make the get request inside the javascript code I've only done it with the thyemeleaf html.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, (i usually use a JavaScript framework) but looks like to make an http request you use something like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest